# Android Loading html file from local folder into webview

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

Task : I have created a fragment drawer where i have i have textview with text "myname" just below my image and then there is nav_row item so what i want to do is when this text is clicked it should switch activity from MainActivity to profileinfo and i have webview created and its activity profileinfo that should load my html file...So what i did is here-->

this is my activity_main xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <webview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/aboutYou"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </webview>
    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.medmainfomatix.mdesign.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

webview xml is here -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/aboutYou"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</webview>
```

profileinfo activity

```
public class profileinfo extends AppCompatActivity{
    private WebView aboutYou;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        aboutYou = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aboutYou);
        aboutYou.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/profile_info.html");
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity class

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

```
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
TextView pname;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    displayView(0);
    pname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);


    pname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,profileinfo.class);

            startActivity(inent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my textview info in this xml fragment navigation drawer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pname"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile_name"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't worry about other class and xml please take a look and where i am wrong.

I am getting this -->
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.medmainfomatix.mdesign, PID: 27497
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign.profileinfo}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class webview
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class webview
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at com.medmainfomatix.mdesign.profileinfo.onCreate(profileinfo.java:16)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.webview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at com.medmainfomatix.mdesign.profileinfo.onCreate(profileinfo.java:16) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.webview" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.1_0a328bfef112abe9401e5ad651d5b475868a0fa2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.medmainfomatix.mdesign/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_c5d6f1d87c5057b6eaca56a24d54d014044b8659-cla

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have edited and posted the error take a look

Comment: and this is coming on that textview mentioned in fragment_navigation_drawer xml when i click it should start profile info activity then load my html

Answer (score 1):

Try this
It works for me

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

use (file:///)full address

Comment: did that already not working for me, problem is coming from clickable textview in fragment_navigation_drawer xml

Comment: take a look at this used this code--->http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/ 

The only thing i am adding is text below the profile image in drawer which should load my html file in activity on the same screen or different either way is fine

Comment: @SameerKhan1406 Iam not sure but you must try .setselected(true)

Comment: Ok so let it go i guess there is something deeper i'll have to dig.....i did this profile info part in MainActivity then its working but it shows webpage not available ERR_FILE_FOUND and i did that same full address thing in my code still it is showing the same error what should i do

Comment: aboutYou.loadUrl("file:///home/abc/AndroidStudioProjects/Mdesign/app/src/main/assets/file.html");